# polkit.service - Authorization Manager fail to activate

Tags: centos, permissions, service

Major issue with polkit service how to fix this its trying and failing to activate polkit every time.

Sorry if noob question.

## systemctl status polkit.service

● polkit.service - Authorization Manager

```
# systemctl status polkit.service
● polkit.service - Authorization Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/polkit.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:polkit(8)

May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV polkitd[5900]: Started polkitd version 0.112
May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV polkitd[5900]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV polkitd[5900]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV polkitd[5900]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 2 rules
May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV polkitd[5900]: Lost the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 - exiting
May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV systemd[1]: Failed to kill control group: Invalid argument
May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV systemd[1]: Failed to kill control group: Invalid argument
May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV systemd[1]: Failed to kill control group: Invalid argument
May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV systemd[1]: Failed to kill control group: Invalid argument
May 30 05:53:32 RJSRV systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
[root@RJSRV ~]# busctl
NAME                              PID PROCESS         USER             CONNECTION    UNIT                      SESSION    DESCRIPTION
:1.0                                1 systemd         root             :1.0          -                         -          -
:1.1                              515 systemd-logind  root             :1.1          systemd-logind.service    -          -
:1.46                            6260 busctl          root             :1.46         session-c1.scope          c1         -
org.freedesktop.DBus                - -               -                -             -                         -          -
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1          - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.hostname1           - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.locale1             - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.login1            515 systemd-logind  root             :1.1          systemd-logind.service    -          -
org.freedesktop.machine1            - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.systemd1            1 systemd         root             :1.0          -                         -          -
org.freedesktop.timedate1           - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
```

Every service i try to restart fail because of this

```
systemctl restart dbus
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Activation of org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 timed out (g-dbus-error-quark, 20)
Failed to restart dbus.service: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Same issue on fresh installs too. It wasn't doing this a while back, it started for no reason now.

Comment: Same issue here, completely unclear what's going on. Why does it lose the name anyway?